# Why does Fermat's little theorem not hold for all composite numbers?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

https://www.quora.com/How-do-you-show-that-Fermats-little-theorem-doesnt-hold-if-p-is-not-prime-number-theory-discrete-mathematics-modular-arithmetic-math/answer/Ted-Alper?ch=10&oid=281989600&share=c2475d1c&srid=hhKMtL&target_type=answer

I was trying to understand the reasoning given above about why Fermat's little theorem does not hold for all composite numbers p where a^(p-1) = 1 mod p.

I can follow the logic up to why GCD(a^(n-1), n) >= a if a is a proper divisor of n, but I don't see how this then leads to the reasoning a^(n-1) can't be congruent to 1 mod n.

Comment: As formulated , a single counterexampe would answer the question. I guess you want to know why Fermat-pseudoprimes to base $a$ are rare no matter which base $a$ we choose.

Comment: @Peter I was thinking about the proof above and got as far as if we assume n = ak, and we assume a^(n-1) = 1 mod n is true, then a^(n-1) = mn + 1 for some number m. This means then the GCD(a^(n-1), n)  = GCD(mn+1, n). We also know GCD(a^(n-1),n) >= a .But we know n = ak so mn +1 = m*a*k + 1. This means m*a*k +1 can't be divisible by a, so can't have a GCD with n that is >= a? But this doesn't seem complete, and while you can show the GCD is not equal to a, how can you show it can't be greater than a?